# Receiving "Exception: Invalid conversion for item type: PAGE_BREAK. (line 60, file "Code") error code due to multiple sections with in the form."

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

Below is my current code and it updates my form based on the spreadsheet columns with the appropriate "id" question but fails once it reaches a page break in the form. I will have multiple forms this will work through to ensure all dropdowns have the same options. For example a new customer is added to the list and needs to be added to different forms. However at this point I can't get it to work through the page breaks.

Hope someone can point me down the right path.

```
var wsData = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID).getSheetByName("FormQuestionEntries");
var form = FormApp.openById(NJEformID)


function main(){
  var labels = wsData.getRange(1,1,1,wsData.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
  labels.forEach(function(label,i){
    var options = wsData
                        .getRange(2,i+1,wsData.getLastRow()-1,1)
                        .getValues()
                        .map(function(o){return o[0]})
                        .filter(function(o){return o !==""});
    updateDropDownUsingTitle(label,options);
  });
}

function updateDropDownUsingTitle(title,values) {
 var items = form.getItems();
 var titles = items.map(function(item){
   return item.getTitle();
 });
  var pos = titles.indexOf(title);
  if(pos !== -1){
    var item = items[pos];
    var itemID = item.getId();
    updateDropdown(itemID,values);  
  }              
}

function updateDropdown(id,values) {
  var item = form.getItemById(id);
  item.asListItem().setChoiceValues(values);
  
 }
```

Comment: I'd suggest sharing an example form and GSheet so people can try and reproduce the problem.

Comment: Could you please share a copy of the form and the spreadsheet (of course, remove all sensitive information)?

Answer (score 0):

You must check that each question is a selector, differentiate the names of the question heading and do not duplicate sections.

```
var titles = items.map(function(item){
   if(item.getType() == 'LIST'){
     return item.getTitle();
   }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you might have row values that don't have a header that is called by the form associated with them in the google sheet. Try to take out all data that doesn't have a header

Comment: Suggestions based on assumptions are best done in comments.

Answer (score -1):

Just make sure there are no Duplicate titles. It should work. It is working for me.

Comment: please use comments to suggest or advice the user.